# Analyze log data with occassional multiline logs

Tags: python-3.x

I need to scan a log file for users that ran certain SQL statements (DROP,CREATE,etc.), and return an array with the users and which SQL ddl's they tried(drop,create,etc.).

I have log files where each line normally looks like this:

```
'2019-01-14T-19:23:50Z UTC' [ db=dev user=joeschmoe pid=123 userid=1 xid=1234]' Log: Select *
```

however, sometimes the select statement will span multiple lines like this:

```
'2019-01-14T19:23:50Z UTC [ db=dev user=rb pid=16 userid=1 xid=8 ]' LOG: SELECT SUM (num_queries) num_all_queries
        ,SUM (CASE WHEN lalala is not null THEN num_queries ELSE 0 END)          num_b
        ,SUM (CASE WHEN lalala is null     THEN num_queries ELSE 0 END)          num_non_b
        ,SUM (total_queue_time_min)                                                     total_queue_time_min
        ,SUM (CASE WHEN lalala is not null THEN total_queue_time_min ELSE 0 END) b_total_queue_time_min
        ,SUM (CASE WHEN lalala is null     THEN total_queue_time_min ELSE 0 END) non_b_total_queue_time_min
        ,SUM (CASE WHEN lalala is not null THEN duration_s ELSE 0 END)/60.0      total_burst_usage_min
        ,SUM (CASE WHEN lalala is not null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)                    num_lalalas
        ,MIN(firsttime)                                                                 mintime
        ,MAX(lasttime)                                                                  maxtime
        ,DATEDIFF (seconds, mintime, maxtime)                                           workload_duration_s
        ,wration_s/60.0                                                       workload_duration_min
LEFT JOIN (SELECT b FROM STfdaf LIMIT 1) sq ON sq.but_reon < 100 
;
```

I am combing these logs for certain keywords in the SQL statements. I can write the regex to handle that but I need help getting this log in a format I can work with. I was originally using a for loop and a regex

```
for line in input:
        user_match = re.search("DROP", line, re.IGNORECASE)
```

This wouldn't be accurate because when a sql statement spans multiple lines I wouldn't be able to tie the "DROP" back to the "USER" if the DROP occurred many lines after the initial line.

I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Whether its turning this text file into a list in python and programmatically combining multiple lines into one or whatever other options there may be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by storing the user value in a variable that only updates if a match is found using RegEx. So if a keyword is found, the user value last stored in the variable would be returned along with the keyword.

```
for line in input:
        error = []
        user_match = re.search("USER=b[0-9]{6}", line, re.IGNORECASE)
        serviceuser = re.search("USER=[a-z0-9]*", line, re.IGNORECASE)
        if serviceuser:
            user = (serviceuser.group().split("=")[1])
        elif user_match: 
            user = (user_match.group().split("=")[1])
        ddl = re.search(
            "LINK|.DELETE.|INSERT|TRIGGER|TRUNCATE|UPDATE|WRITE", line, re.IGNORECASE)

        if ddl:
            error.append(user)
            error.append(ddl.group())
```